# Bonferroni adjustment of studentized residuals for outlier detection

Tags: outliers

Here is the statement that I have read ([source](http://polisci.msu.edu/jacoby/icpsr/regress3/lectures/week3/11.Outliers.pdf) pp. 21-23):

> Since we are selecting the furthest outlier, it is not legitimate to
>   use a simple t-test(for studentized residuals) for detecting outliers. To remedy this we can make a Bonferroni adjustment to the p-value

**Questions:**

(1) Why can't we use simple t-test?

(2) How does a Bonferroni adjustment help us solve the problem?

Comment: Can you give us the context?

Comment: @StudentT I added the document. Pages 21-23

Comment: The Bonferroni p-value adjustment is used for multiple testing.  Outlier detection is a very different matter which relates to subject matter knowledge and has many issues including the masking effect (a second outlier hides the existence of the first.